# Server Error '/" Application C# asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

> Parser Error Description: An error
>   occurred during the parsing of a
>   resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following
>   specific parse error details and
>   modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load
>   type 'SafeNet_WebPage.admin.project'.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="project.aspx.cs" Inherits="SafeNet_WebPage.admin.project" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

This project.aspx are locating in one folder with other news.aspx and when I load news it s all ok, it does what it make to do, but when i load project i get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have Viewed your issue on TeamViewer, your button is not added in your form Designer class as you have copied the button and event handler from another page.

What I did for you was to add a button from the toolbox and its Designer class. After it is refreshed and your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the code behind class is named `SafeNet_WebPage.admin.project` as this is what it's looking for and can't find. Also make sure it's built and deployed properly.